# Smart way in Java to test for a method value in a null-proof way?

Tags: java

Does anybody know whether there is a way in Java to compare method values without the need for a separate call to check that the method doesn't return null? Eg, given a class like

```
public class Person{
  private String name;
  public String getName(){
     return name;
  }
  //...other stuff here
}
```

and then in another class we have a test like this:

```
if (person.getName() != null && person.getName().equals(otherPerson.getName()){
  //do something
}
```

what I'm wondering is what's the cleanest way to do this? In classes that have 10 or more members it gets messy to run so many null-checks and then value-comparison-checks.

Any hints or ideas are much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Objects.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to safely equate null values to each other in Java 7:

```
if (Objects.equals(person.getName(), otherPerson.getName()) { ... }
```

Of course, this doesn't stop exceptions if `person` or `otherPerson` is null, for which you'll need to do your own null check beforehand. If you're not using 7, you could easily write your own version of this method.

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.equals

Comment: Thanks! This is useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305)'s `@Nullable` / `@Nonnull` annotations. Most modern IDEs can check whether they are used properly and warn you if not.

Comment: `@Nonnull` with both n in lowercase I think

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This might work if I could add it as a restriction, unfortunately those methods are allowed to return null. There's a bit of legacy code too.

Comment: @DianaAmza I know. I am facing the same situation. Still: using these annotations still makes things easier and less error prone, especially with Findbugs and / or IntelliJ idea

Answer (score 0):

This extra boilerplate is one of the major downsides of Java. Groovy makes this easier with the ?. operator. There you can simply do:

```
if (person.getName()?.equals(otherPerson.getName()){
  //do something
}
```

If getName() returns null, the ?. operator returns null and the expression is evaluated as false.

In Java, the best solution is probably using StringUtils from Apache Commons:

> [`StringUtils.equals(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

That allows you to do stuff like:

```
StringUtils.equals(null, "abc");
```

Comment: Agreed, that's a bit annoying. Thanks for the Groovy tip, didn't know that.